# SciFi novel about scientist, terraforming and soldiers

Tags: story-identification, novel, planets

I read this novel back on deployment 5 years ago. The cover was red with a polaroid photo of a green army man toy holding what appears to be a flamethrower and he is in background of grass.

A team of soldiers and scientists get stranded on a planet and one of the scientists is the main character. They are their to terraform the planet but end up getting stranded. You come to find out later that the scientist is actually a lot older than he appears, he has been able to transfer his consciousness and has been alive for a very long time. He is also hunted by a friend in the past that wants to take everything he loves. Main character developers a relationship with one of the female soldiers.

Comment: Not going to make it an answer but it could be one of the old man war books by john scalzi

Comment: The cover sounds a lot like [_Red Claw_](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1057375) by Philip Palmer. I haven't read the book, so I don't know if the plot matches.

Comment: HOLY POOP! Thank you so much, it is Red Claw, i will be adding it to my collectio.

Answer (score 6):

Submitted since comments can get deleted, and it's been over 4 years.

[sjl](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/2258/sjl) identified the book as "Red Claw" in a comment.

> The cover sounds a lot like [*Red Claw*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1057375) by Philip Palmer. I
> haven't read the book, so I don't know if the plot matches.

The questioner [user24469](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/24469/user24469) accepted the ID in a comment.

> HOLY POOP! Thank you so much, it is Red Claw, i will be adding it to
> my collectio.